# what does fold_idx really mean and what does it do?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
for model in models:
    model_name = model.__class__.__name__
    accuracies = cross_val_score(model, X_res_train, y_res_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=CV)
    for fold_idx, accuracy in enumerate(accuracies):
        entries.append((model_name, fold_idx, accuracy))
```

Comment: There, it's just a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the index number of the row in 'accuracies'

For example if you have this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Marca temporal':[1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7], 'Temperatura':[37,84,55, 60,61,72,36,94]})

accuracies = df["Temperatura"]

for fold_idx, accuracy in enumerate(accuracies):
    print(fold_idx, accuracy)
```

You can notice it prints the index of each item, and then the item itself